# Sending excel file from a Blob Storage to a REST Endpoint in Azure Functions with Node

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-functions, serverless

Working on a small personal project where I can drop an .xlsx file on Azure Blob and it'll trigger( Node.js Blob Storage Trigger fn ) and send to a REST endpoint to be parsed and worked with etc.

I've been able to set it up and have the file be moved to another blob( intend to set up logic on the HTTP response to REST endpoint to then archive said file);

I'm not exactly sure how to set up the correct code and bindings to take the ingested .xlsx file and send the whole thing to an endpoint.

Bonus Question: is it better practice to zip the file or convert to binary or anything before sending? Performance isn't too big of a concern currently.

Thanks for any information or any pointers.

Answer (score 0):

The recommended approach is to use event grid trigger of blob storage to trigger an event grid trigger based Azure function. Please refer these which seems to meet your requirement
[Blob Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-event-overview) and [Event Grid Trigger For Azure Function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-event-grid-trigger?tabs=javascript).

Note: Using blob trigger of Azure function may not be as reliable as Event Grid trigger for high volume scenario.

To answer to your bonus question, I think it won't be much beneficial to zip your .xlsx files since those are already compressed behind the scene.